# JSON AUTO in SQL Server Query is Duplicating Records in Parent Array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I am using FOR JSON AUTO on Azure SQL to return my query in JSON and the JSON AUTO part is not quite working fully. I have multiple subtables
in my query and SQL Server is returning a duplicate subtable record and I can't figure out why.

job_id 6 has 3 matching tasks records. But two are showing up in the first item in the results array and on is in the last item in
the result array.

Here is the query:

```sql
select (
    select
      jobs.project_id,
      jobs.job_id,
      jobs.job_name,
      jobs.date_time_due as job_due,
      jobs.date_time_start as job_start,
      jobs.date_time_end as job_end,
      jobs.location as job_location, 
      tasks.task_id,
      tasks.task_name,
      tasks.date_time_start as task_start,
      tasks.date_time_end as task_end,
      tasks.assignments_filled,
      tasks.notes as task_notes,
      tasks.location as task_location,
      tasks.task_type_id,
      tasks.caption_tools_id,
      contractors.contractor_id,
      contractors.name
    from jobs as jobs
    join tasks as tasks on tasks.job_id = jobs.job_id
    left join contractor_task as contractor_task on tasks.task_id = contractor_task.task_id
    left join contractors as contractors on contractors.contractor_id = contractor_task.contractor_id
    where project_id = 6
    FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) as json
```

Here is a subset of the results showing the duplicate record:

```js
    [
     {
      "project_id": 6,
      "job_name": "Retool  Show Filter Button Bug.mp4",
      "job_id": 6,
      "job_location": "Classroom",
      "tasks": [
       {
        "task_name": "Transcribe Video 123",
        "task_location": "",
        "task_start": "2022-09-02T01:30:00",
        "contractors": [
         {
          "contractor_id": 1,
          "name": "Brad Mathews"
         },{
          "contractor_id": 2,
          "name": "Fred Mathews"
         }],
        "task_end": null,
        "assignments_filled": false,
        "task_notes": "",
        "task_type_id": 3,
        "task_id": 12,
        "caption_tools_id": null
       },{
        "task_name": "Post Video Transcription Processing",
        "task_location": null,
        "task_start": null,
        "contractors": [
         {
          "contractor_id": 1,
          "name": "Brad Mathews"
         }],
        "task_end": null,
        "assignments_filled": false,
        "task_notes": null,
        "task_type_id": 4,
        "task_id": 13,
        "caption_tools_id": null
       }],
      "job_start": "2022-09-23T00:45:00",
      "job_end": "2022-09-22T00:45:00",
      "job_due": "2022-09-15T00:00:00"
     },
     ......
     ,{
      "project_id": 6,
      "job_name": "Retool  Show Filter Button Bug.mp4",
      "job_id": 6,
      "job_location": "Classroom",
      "tasks": [
       {
        "task_name": "test Task",
        "task_location": "Home",
        "task_start": "2022-09-15T12:15:00",
        "contractors": [
         {
          "contractor_id": null,
          "name": null
         }],
        "task_end": null,
        "assignments_filled": false,
        "task_notes": "Notes Here",
        "task_type_id": 1,
        "task_id": 102,
        "caption_tools_id": null
       }],
      "job_start": "2022-09-23T00:45:00",
      "job_end": "2022-09-22T00:45:00",
      "job_due": "2022-09-15T00:00:00"
     }]
```

Comment: Sample tables and data, and expected results would help immensely. Formatting your query also makes it much more readable.

Comment: `FOR JSON AUTO` basically guesses at the structure of your JSON. A much better options is multiple `FOR JSON PATH` nested in subqueries

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I did ultimately move to `JSON PATH` and learned how to spec my formatting. As my requirements got more complex `AUTO` really fell down.  And it also dodged this duplication issue. And that is how I format my queries - how my mind works ;-). I was hoping someone would know from experience why such duplications happen, I did not expect to waste people's time digging through my whole dataset for clues, so did not include that.

Comment: Not your whole dataset, just the table structure and a some sample rows, so that we coul run your query